# working on SDK vc++ to c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sdk, wrapper

i am trying to integrate  [zoom.us](https://zoom.us/) SDK to Windows WPF application.
zoom.us provide SDK for windows that is made in vc++.
so my questions is how i can access SDK to c# wpf application.

please help how can we access .lib or convert to .dll or how to work with SDK in c#.

thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

You need to write or find a wrapper for it.If there is none,then create c++ cli project and make an api for your application which basicly talks with sdk and calls proper functions for your wpf.

Comment: oh...yes i am new for all this wrapper,cli etc.i will search on it.

Comment: Can you help me how to find wrapper and create cli project?